# JPA-entities from separate bundles which used one connection from main bundle

Tags: java, jpa, osgi, equinox, eclipse-rap

I want split my RAP application into separate bundles.

First bundle - is main module. It contains common functions as navigation menu, opening database connection. (database oracle)

Other bundles is plugins modules, which contains views, jpa-entities, business-logic.

I need one database connection per application, per user, but I need jpa-entities in separate bundles and in main module. I don't need database connection per each plugin.

All plugins may work with main-module-entities.

Only plugin may work with self-plugin-module-entities.

Main module don't knows about entities in plugins.

Is it possible? Which framework can help me?

Sorry for my english :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have the entity classes in separate bundles, but:

- you must have a persistence.xml file where all entity classes are listed
- the bundle that contains the persistence-unit must import the packages where the entity classes are located

In short: You can have entity classes in separate modules, but you must have a main place where you collect all the information for the PU.

If I understand your question well, you want to have a main module that contains the PU but does not know about the entity classes. Sorry, it is not possible.

**Alternative:**

We had similar requirements so we decided to leave JPA and switch to [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) and QueryDSL[2](http://www.querydsl.com/) combination. Liquibase is used to define the database schema and QueryDSL is used to construct the database independent SQL typesafe statements. With JPA words: No entity classes but only static-metamodel.

We also developed some modules and a maven plugin to support these technologies. It is undocumented yet but if you are interested in this technology stack, I can provide more details.